# Assign and compare in a single statement in C

Tags: c

How can I convert the following code to a single line?

```
int *i;
i = some_func_ret_int_ptr();
if(!i)
{
   // Do something
}
// Will use 'i' later
```

I want to do something like:

```
if((i=some_func_ret_int_ptr) && !i)
{
   // Do something
}
// Will use 'i' later
```

But I am wasting one comparison here. Is there a better way to do it?

All I want is assignment and comparison in the `if` and compare only `i`.

Comment: if you're just learning C, then don't try for fancy/complicated syntax. You'll just confuse yourself. And make it harder to maintain for any unlucky person who has to deal with your code later on.

Comment: I am long term c user. Was doing similar thing at 15-20 places in a file so thought of asking to write it better

Comment: write for clarity, not brevity. it'll compile down to the same binary anyways, so make everyone else's life easier.

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to know if there was a better way.

Comment: A function call is always more expensive than an  in-line extra test. Extra source lines cost nothing, performancewise.

Comment: Your version is not just "wasting one comparison", it is not equivalent.

Comment: @AndreyT I said "I want to do something like". I never said its equivalent.

Comment: For everyone suggesting writing this in two lines for better readability: Yes, with an `if`, I agree. However, if you want a `while` instead of the `if`, this is definitely useful to avoid code duplication. I personally value code duplication avoidance higher then readability.

Comment: `But I am wasting one comparison here. Is there a better way to do it?` <- TBH, most of the answers here will be mushed about by the optimizer and come out much the same (assuming you're using `-O2` or above), so I wouldn't sweat it - `less characters` != `faster/better code`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to what is suggested in other answers, you can also do it as

```
if (i = some_func_ret_int_ptr(), !i)
{
  // Do something
}
```

It is a literal implementation of what you had originally, with the statement sequence replaced with an expression sequence separated by the `,` operator.

It does not make much practical sense, though.

Comment: You can express the same thing by `if(!(i = …))`

Comment: @dom0: Yes, you can. Or you can do it as I suggested.

Answer (score 8):

With C, this is as far as you can golf it:

```
int *i;
if(!(i = some_func_ret_int_ptr()))
{
   // do something
}
// Will use i later
```

Comment: Huh? It's functionally equivalent to the code you provided. And it will only evaluate if the assignment failed (or it was assigned 0).

Comment: @Siddharth: What does "assignment succeded" mean? How can assignment "succeed" or "not succeed"?

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
if(!(i = some_func_ret_int_ptr()))
{
      ...
}
```

What happens in this code, in order, is:

1. The return value of `some_func_ret_int_ptr()` is assigned to `i`
2. The statement `!i` is checked
3. If `i == 0` what's inside the `if` gets executed, otherwise it will not

Comment: I pointed out that I need to store the value in i. Will use it later on in the code.

Comment: @SiddharthL this does store the return value in `i`; you can have an assignment statement in an `if` condition.

Comment: @JohnBode my reply was before the edit. Code at point of reply was if(!some_func_ret_int_ptr())

Answer (score 2):

Clean and readable:

```
int * i = some_func_ret_int_ptr();

if (!i) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: How is that an answer ? Isn't that same as I already have ? Starting with int *i; was suggesting that there is some code in between. Also, mixed declaration in C code will give you linting errors.

Comment: @Siddharth "lint" is from a time when cc was crap and someone made lint instead of giving cc better warnings. Now cc has good warnings so there's no point linting. Anyway, mixed declaration is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

An option not mentioned yet is:

```
if ( NULL != (i = some_func()) )
```

Using the explicit comparison against `NULL` makes it very easy to read the intent of this code. Especially considering that your function probably won't have `ret_int_ptr` in its name.

Comment: yes that function name was just to explain the pseudo-code

Answer (score 0):

Using the `#include <ctype.h>` standard library, to get the `toupper(char)` function, we can write the following function:

```
void StringToUppercase(char* str)
{
    for (int i=0; (str[i] = toupper(str[i])) != 0; i++);  // No for-loop body!
    // The expression "(str[i] = toupper(str[i]))" executes first and then returns str[i]
}
```

so that the statement `(str[i] = toupper(str[i])) != 0;` both assigns a char and checks to see if it is `'\0'` or not.

The way this works is that part of the C language specifies that assignment expressions have the value of the lefthand expressions after the assignment. For example, with ints, consider the following code snippet:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x = 8;

// Assignment operators (= += <<=) have right-to-left associativity.
// The expression `(x=8)` returns the value 8, after it has been executed

int z = x != y;  // Comparisons have greater (tighter) precedence than assignment
printf("(x, y, z) = (%d, %d, %d)\n", x, y, z);  // prints (8, 8, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as [M.M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266839/assign-and-compare-in-a-single-statement-in-c/26268313#26268313), but I would go with:

```
if ((i = some_func_ret_int_ptr()) != NULL)
```

As it makes the execution order clearer.

Comment: Which answer is "last" depends on how you sort them.  In any case, this is better suited to being a comment on the answer you mean - earn a little reputation and you'll be able to post comments very soon.